# Task oriented thread pooling

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I've created a model for executing worker tasks in a server application using a thread pool associated with an IO completion port such as shown in the posts below:

http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2008/01/03/parallel-programming-with-c-part-4-i-o-completion-ports.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2004/03/29/101329.aspx

Are there any classes in boost that can help with this programming model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, at least, not last time I looked.  I mean, boost::thread_group might make things marginally tidier in places, but not so as would make much of a difference, I don't think.

Boost's thread support seems marginally useful when writing something that's cross-platform, but given that what you're writing is going to be Win32-specific anyway (due to the use of IOCPs) there doesn't really seem to be much benefit from that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [threadpool project](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/), which looks like a nice threadpool implementation on top of boost.  I haven't tried it myself, but it looks fairly nice.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anything in boost that helps with the structure that you tend to end up with when using IO Completion Ports, but then I haven't looked that recently... However, slightly off-topic, you might like to take a look at the IOCP based thread pool that is part of my free IOCP server framework. It might give you some ideas if nothing else. You can find the code [here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html). The thread pool supports expansion and contraction based on demand and has been in use in production systems for over 6 years.

Answer (score 0):

[ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) has some reactors that you can use to model things around your IOCPs.  Some of these could have been added to boost, but boost makes building them pretty easy.